# Only partially chaning font size in a line in python

Tags: python, string, figure, letter

I have been wondering how I could change only a few letters in one line in figure labels and titles. Thank you for your insights.

For example:

[image]

Comment: Kei, I brought the image inline to ensure readers didn't have to click on a link. But I *do* hope that's just an example since it's pretty ugly :-) You might want to provide more detail as to what framework you're using for those "labels and titles", it'll make the question easier to answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to do this once, you could consider making a few classes.

```
<style>
#my-content{
    display: inline;
}
.font-a{
    font-family:'FontA', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;

}
.font-b{
    font-family:'FontB', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
}
</style>



<div id='my-content'>
    <div class='font-a'>Fig</div>
    <div class='font-b'>u</div>
    <div class='font-a'>re </div>
    <div class='font-b'>T</div>
    <div class='font-a'>itle</div>
<div>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to provide an example code including figure plotting? I wonder where these can fit in the code.

Comment: @Kei Not sure what you mean by figure plotting. Could you edit your post to include your current code?